# Is this method of checkbox validation safe

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core

- I have the following model in an asp.net mvc application

```
using  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class UserAgreementModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "please show your approval of agreement")]
        [Range(1,1,ErrorMessage = "please show your approval of agreement")]
        public byte UserAgrees { get; set; }


    }
```

- In my view I have a hidden field representing the byte property above and a check box changing its value

```
  <input type="checkbox" >
<div class="form-group">'
                <input type="text" asp-for="UserAgrees" style="visibility:hidden"  value="0" class="form-control" />  
                <span asp-validation-for="UserAgrees" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

- And the jquery code  to change value

```
$(function () {
        $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function()
        {
            $("#UserAgrees").val($(this).is(":checked")?"1":"0")
        })
    })
```

- Now the form does not get submitted unless checkbox is checked
- Is this way of validation safe,since the field is bound to a property in the model?
- regards

Comment: Hi @Basem AlShabani,you use Range attribute and add the limit value,so that you have server side validation now,and you just need use ModelState.IsValid to validate the value.Besides,you need add `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in your view and then you will get the client side validation by default.So you have both server side and client side validation,this is a safe way to validation.

Comment: @Rena yes the jquery validation files exist and the validation is working but what if user changes the value of hidden field by pressing f12 in the browser

Comment: Hi @Basem AlShabani,so what you want is you must press the checkbox to change the value?If so,it seems the question does not relate to the model validation.You need add listener to the checkbox.